# Node.js Asynchronous return from HTTP request

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm very new to JS and node. I am trying to return a variable from an asynchronous http request, and I recognize that the problem is the async nature of the call, but cannot figure out how to make a very simple code snippet function despite reading multiple tutorials.

Can someone please mark this up such that it works and I can digest it and modify for my own use? Should I be using the async library? I've taken a couple of attempts and haven't been able to make that work.

```html
var request = require('request');
a = 0;

a = foo();
function foo() {
   var num = 1;
   request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
        // console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
        //console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
        //console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
        num = 3;
        return callback(num);
    })
   return num;
}

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: Your return returns somewhere into the *request* module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am going to assume that you are making your request correctly, and instead focus on the idea of the callback. If you try this and still need a little more help let me know.

I will try to keep this code close to what you already have:

```
function foo(callback){
   request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
      if(error)
        console.log(error);
      //console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
      // Print the response status code if a response was received
      //console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
      num = 3;
      callback(num);
    })
}
```

then in order to print a 3 out you would do something like this.

```
foo(function(value){
   console.log(value);
})
```

You would see the value 3 printed out in this case.

If you wanted to return more then just 3 you would need to pass them as parameters to the callback function that has been passed in. If you were to try to follow callback style more you would probably get something closer to this.

```
function foo(callback){
   request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
     if(error)
        callback(error,null);
     //do what ever you need to with the response and body
     num = 3;
     callback(null,num);
    })
} 
foo(function(err, value){
   if(err)
      console.log(err);
   console.log(value);
})
```

You just need to remember that with callbacks, like Rob mentions, you typically don't return. Instead, you have your function call another function that you pass in, and provide that function with parameters that your function determined.

Comment: Thank you! This clearly works and will require me to structure my code differently. Much appreciated. Does it make sense to try to do this with async/await?

Comment: I will admit that I am not very familiar with async await. With something as simple as this I wouldn't use async await. For me it really depends on the complexity of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

You must/can only operate on the results of an async call within its callback because

1. callbacks do not return values,
2. callbacks do not  have access to your surrounding context, so in your example `num` is not defined when the callback is triggered, and
3. you cannot know when the callback completes and thus its result is available.

In your example code, foo will always *immediately* return `1` irrespective of the response/body returned from `request`.